# Collection view loading only one cell at a time

Tags: swift, loading, collectionview, indexpath

Edited

I am using custom collection cells to load in collectionview. But when the collection view loadeds expecting behaviour cellforindex delegate will call for 3 indexpath but in this case only calling 0th indexpath 3 time.

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "cellName", bundle: nil)
        self.collectionvView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
       return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
              cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        print("indexpath.row ----------------- ",indexPath.row)

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId",for: indexPath) as! DetailCollectionViewCell
         return cell

    }
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Post your `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` method.

Comment: Provide **full** code for `cellForRow`.

Answer (score 0):

Check All This

1. self.arrIds.count = 3
2. numberOfSections = 1
3. numberOfItemsInSection
4. cellForItemAt

Comment: Hi i have checked all these steps, and array count is 10.

Comment: In numberOfItemsInSection use array.count and put break point to all the method and check log for index path.row